# How to get image to show using s3 and paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using paperclip and AWS for my Rails app to upload image. You can find it here: http://lit-stream-6263.herokuapp.com/

When I try to upload images, I don't get an error but for some reason the image doesn't show. When I go into the S3 bucket though, I'm able to see the image that gets uploaded...it's just not rendering in the html page. Any advice on how to fix this?

Update
From 9nonnatus, I'm seeing the picture if I change the URL.  However in my rails view I have

```
<%= image_tag product.avatar.url(:medium) %>
```

to display the image. This is what I see in the documentation as well. How do I adjust this to fit the url you mention above?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :blog_link, :blog_name, :description, :image_link, :name, :num_likes, :product_link, :avatar
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

end
```

Comment: can you show the code in your model? just the `has_attached_file` part, your image tag looks correct - unless you are not specifying a style of `:medium` during upload

Comment: just added the code for the Product model

Comment: code looks ok - if you go directly to http://s3.amazonaws.com/rockywolfugc/products/avatars/000/000/003/medium/59577_10100258833612183_1508749_n.jpg?1386876682 @9nonnatus is correct, have you done any special configuration to your s3 setup? we use paper_clip `url` method which is generating `http://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET_NAME/` url without issue?

Comment: take a look at: http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3 - note the `url` option, guessing you need to do `:url => ":s3_domain_url"`

Comment: Where do I include this in my production.rb and heroku? If you answer at the link below, I can give you credit :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558281/how-to-edit-production-rb-in-my-rails-app-to-get-it-working-using-heroku-and-pap

Comment: You can probably put it in has_attached_file or in paperclip defaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of the page you can copy the image link and try to access it in your browser. It gives an error telling you that your hyperlinks are incorrectly formatted. Instead of making the `img src` format something like:

`http://s3.amazonaws.com/rockywolfugc/products/avatars/000/000/003/medium/59577_10100258833612183_1508749_n.jpg?1386876682`

you have to use this format:

`http://rockywolfugc.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/products/avatars/000/000/003/medium/59577_10100258833612183_1508749_n.jpg?1386876682`

In other words, remove `/rockywolfugc` from after `.com` and replace `s3` with `rockywolfugc.s3-us-west-2`

Hope that helps.

Comment: In my rails view I have <%= image_tag product.avatar.url(:medium) %>. This is what I see in the documentation as well. How do I adjust this to fit the url you mention above?