# How to edit production.rb in my rails app to get it working using heroku and paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, paperclip

I am using paperclip + AWS in my rails app to upload images.

When I reference images in my view as

```
<%= image_tag product.avatar.url(:medium) %>
```

current image urls are showing up as:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/rockywolfugc/products/avatars/000/000/003/medium/59577_10100258833612183_1508749_n.jpg?1386876682
```

I need them to show up as:

```
http://rockywolfugc.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/products/avatars/000/000/003/medium/59577_10100258833612183_1508749_n.jpg?1386876682
```

At http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3 I'm seeing there is an option for ":s3_domain_url" but I'm not quite sure how to use it.

Below is the relevant portion of production.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Where do I integrate the s3_domain_url in this file? Additionally, what do I have to do on heroku to get this to run? Example: heroku config:set xxxx=yyyy

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424724/ruby-on-rails-paperclip-amazon-aws-s3-heroku

Answer (score 0):

try setting

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['AWS_BUCKET_NAME']}.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
```

in your production.rb

Comment: Hm that didn't work. It also changed the host for my css files.